# Share datas at the end of a Service

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I would like to have your opinion. 
I have got an **Activity A** with a button (and a listener of course). It starts a Service **and** a Notification.
I would like that when I click on the notification, it runs a new **Activity B** and it stops the Service. 
My problem is : how use an Indent to send the datas **from the Service to the Activity B** when the Service is stop? 
 (I need the very last values of datas in my Service) 
Thanks in advance for yours answers.

Answer (score 1):

`Intent` has a couple of methods called `putExtra(String name, ...)` which allow you to put a number of EXTRAS on the intent. You don't specify a whole lot of detail in your question. This is the most generic answer I can give you.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm going to give you more details : I tried to use an Indent and the methods putExtras() in onDestroy() of my Service because i thank that the method stopService() in my activity called onDestroy() but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show some of your code? `onDestroy()` is called when the `Service` is destroyed, which will usually happen some time after `stopService` is called, _unless_ the `Service` is also "bound", but `stopService` does not _call_ `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Sorry I can't show my code but now my question is simple : how share the datas (of my Service) only when the Service is stopped ?

Comment: Create an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and we may be able to help you. This is too broad, unless you can show us exactly what you're trying to do, it'll be hard for people to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time ci_. I don't show my code, not because i don't want but because i've a confidentiality clause but thanks again.

Comment: How does that stop you from creating an MCVE? Have you even looked at the link I provided? Anyway suit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling stopSelf() on the service you should start the Activity B with the intent (say I). Immediately after calling startActivity(B, I), you should call stopSelf on service.

While creating I, you can put data into the intent as EXTRAs.

Comment: Thanks sushantsha but how i call stopSelf with my Notification ? It's not the Service which stops itself but my Notification (or an activity it's doesn't matter) which do it